# Default constructor getting called while using virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In the following code when I create the object of C then A'a default constructor is getting called through B's constructor, why is that happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int a;
    A(int z): a(z) {cout<<"a is "<<a;}
    A() { cout<<" it came here\n";}
};

class B: public virtual A
{
public:
    B(int z): A(z) {cout<<"in B and z is "<<z<<"\n"; }
};

class C:public B
{
public:
    C(int z): B(z) {cout<<" In C\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    C b(6);
    cout<<b.a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is another alternative for why it is called, directly related to it being a *virtual* base of `B`, from which C is derived. Hint: B's constructor isn't the source, so think again on that.

Comment: A(int z): a(z) {cout<<"a is "<<a;}  Is this line of code correct? It is either intended to be cyclic constructor call or it is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how virtual inheritance is described in the standard.

> [12.6.2] — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class *base-specifier-list*.

In particular, when constructing `C`, the `A` subobject is initialized before anything else (including the `B` subobject). Since `A` is not in the `mem-initializers` list of the offending `C` constructor, the default constructor of `A` is used for that.

> [12.6.2] — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

Then the `B` subobject is constructed.

> [12.6.2] A *mem-initializer* where the *mem-initializer-id* denotes a virtual base class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that is not the most derived class.

`: A(z)` in the constructor of `B` is ignored when constructing the `B` subobject of `C`.

In the everyday language this means you have to initialize a virtual base class in each direct or indirect derived class, as if it were a direct derived class. If you forget to do so, a default constructor will be forced, with potentially devastating consequences. (That's why you should strive to have either *only* the default constructor or *no* default constructor at all in any virtual base class).

Comment: Hi n.m, thank you for such detailed answer now I am clear on these things